# How can I add an "ex" LocalParams to a Facet Field Query in SolrNet?

Tags: solrnet

If I use a SolrFacetFieldQuery to build a facet query, I can't add the LocalParams in the constructor because when it parses the other facet parameters such as Limit and Sort, it will add the LocalParams to the name of the field, which generates an invalid query for example:

```
var fq = new SolrFacetFieldQuery(new LocalParams{{"ex", "c"}} + "category") { Limit = 10 };
```

I would like to generate:

```
facet.field={!ex=c}category&facet.category.limit=10&fq={!tag=c}category:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [fixed a couple of weeks ago](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=133).